# Postgresql Query to extract records where there are 365 readings for distinct years in a datestamp field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data set like below where I need my query to return only values if there are 365 readings for each distinct year ( I need to make sure I have full year records) for each station in native_id field:

```
native_id                          datestamp               val 
charachter varying(50)                date              double precision
------------------------------------------------------------------------
08GD008                             2017-01-11              1.14
08GE002                             2017-01-11              88.67
08MC040                             2017-05-07              4.61
08FB006                             2017-01-11              13.70       
08FC003                             2017-01-11               37
08LF002                             2017-01-11               2.5
```

Here is what I could think of so far but it is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE COUNT DISTINCT (EXTRACT year FROM "datestamp" = 365)
```

Comment: 365 reading per what? What about leap years?

Comment: You need a calendar table (or sub expression) I.e. a table expression that contains a value for every date. Then you can join on that.

Comment: @dnoeth yes you are right, I need full years as well as leap years

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is harder than you think, because of leap years.  Assuming that there are no duplicates, you can use date arithmetic:

```
SELECT native_id, EXTRACT(year FROM datestamp) as yyyy
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY native_id, yyyy
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAKE_DATE(EXTRACT(year FROM datestamp)::int + 1, 1, 1) - MAKE_DATE(EXTRACT(year FROM datestamp)::int, 1, 1);
```

If there are duplicates, then use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  However, that is more expensive performance-wise, so don't use `DISTINCT` if not needed.

You can then get the original data by doing:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE (native_id, EXTRACT(year FROM datestamp)::int) IN
        (SELECT native_id, EXTRACT(year FROM datestamp)::int as yyyy
         FROM TABLE 
         GROUP BY native_id, yyyy
         HAVING COUNT(*) = MAKE_DATE(EXTRACT(year FROM datestamp)::int + 1, 1, 1) - MAKE_DATE(EXTRACT(year FROM datestamp)::int, 1, 1)
        );
```

Comment: Come on, Gordon, HAVING instead of WHERE and in the 2nd Select there's something missing: `WHERE (native_id, )`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have not downvoted the answer ... I am trying to make it work

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for your help ... I am getting this error though  ERROR:  function make_date(double precision, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 8:          HAVING COUNT(*) = MAKE_DATE(EXTRACT(year FROM dates...
                                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 217t

Comment: @SinaShabani . . . That is so weird.  `extract()` returns a double value, which doesn't get converted to an int.  Somehow, I hadn't realized this.